# UIWebview set delegate method in a class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

How can i set the delegate method of a UIWebView in a class?

when i do it, the app carsh.

---

```
@interface MineWebViewHandle : NSObject<UIWebViewDelegate>

@end
```

//.m

```
@implementation MineWebViewHandle

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *urlString = [[request URL] absoluteString];

    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"did start load");
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"did finished ");
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"webview error:%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

---

i use it:

```
    self.m_pWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    MineWebViewHandle *handle = [[MineWebViewHandle alloc]init];
    self.m_pWebView.delegate = handle;
    self.m_pWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.m_pWebView];
```

how do i use it rightly?

Comment: Can you add the crash message?

Comment: Why are you giving zero frame to your webview? Also as mentioned in above comment that could u post the crash message.

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate look like is create in viewDidLoad,and in the end of this it´s release (put to nil).

You need create a property called: MineWebViewHandle *handle.

in your viewController.h add:

```
 @property (nonatomic,strong)MineWebViewHandle *handle;
```

and change in your code:

```
self.handle = [[MineWebViewHandle alloc]init];
self.m_pWebView.delegate = self. handle;
```

And it´s good idea your webView will have dimensions, change this:

```
self.m_pWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

Comment: Thank you! this helps me! yes,i did it in viewDidLoad! but i think that In ARC, "MineWebViewHandle *handle = [[MineWebViewHandle alloc]init]" handle will have a strong point.why is it released?

Comment: No matter how the strong points an object has, if its reference counting is zero the object will be released. The problem is your object handle has a +1 (alloc), but at the end of the methods receive a -1, and is destructed. Nevertheless, if you put it in an strong property another +1 will be added.

Answer (score -1):

`Webview` is the `UIView`, Not a controler.

Please remove the `NSObject` and add the `UIview`

```
@interface MineWebViewHandle : UIView
@end
```